# Operation Cannot consume content type is not supported. when trying to upload a file to sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

We are making a POST to 
`sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/{realm_id}/attachable`

with header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="--fdlkjflksd--"
```

and body:

```
--fdlkjflksd--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_metadata_01"; filename="attachment.json"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
{"AttachableRef": [{"EntityRef": {"type": "Purchase", "value": "144"}}], "FileName": "one_pixel.jpeg", "ContentType": "image/jpeg"}
--fdlkjflksd--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content_01"; filename="one_pixel.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
/9j/2wBDAP//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAALCAABAAEBAREA/8QAFAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//EABQQAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2gAIAQEAAD8AN//Z
--fdlkjflksd--
```

and we are getting in response:

```
{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Unsupported Operation","Detail":"Operation Cannot consume content type is not supported.","code":"500"}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2020-03-07T03:00:51.600-08:00"}
```

we followed [this example](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/attach-images-and-notes#attaching-a-file-to-an-object)

Answer (score 2):

The `/attachable` endpoint is for *linking EXISTING attachments* to an object, and the `Content-Type` is:

- `application/json`

Docs are here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/attach-images-and-notes#attaching-a-note-to-an-object

The `/upload` endpoint is for *uploading NEW attachments*, and the `Content-Type` is:

- `multipart/form-data`

Docs: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/attach-images-and-notes#uploading-files-to-the-attachment-list

It looks like you've mixed then up - it looks like you're trying to upload a new file to the *existing file* endpoint.